# Springboot json to model without default constructor

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot

I'd encounter a problem and i can't figure it out.

## Context

I have a controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/classroom")
public class ClassroomController {

    @Inject
    private ClassroomManager classroomManager;

    @RequestMapping(value= "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Classroom create(Classroom classroom) {
        ... some checks ...
        return classroomManager.create(classroom);
    }
}
```

A model class :

```
public class Classroom {

    private Long id;
    private final String name;
    private final RoomCapacity roomCapacity;
    private final Set<RoomEquipment> equipments = new HashSet<>();
    [... No setter, No default constructor ...]



    public Classroom(String name, RoomCapacity roomCapacity) {
        [... some checks ...]
        this.name = name;
        this.roomCapacity = roomCapacity;
    }
}
```

The problem is, i can't send POST request with a Classroom as JSON.

When i do so, i'm faced to this exception :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.ubp.ent.backend.core.model.classroom.Classroom]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.ubp.ent.backend.core.model.classroom.Classroom.<init>()
```

## What is my question

I do understand the error, i might add a default constructor to the class.
But the point `Classroom` is from model, i don't want to allow default instantiation.

How can i make Spring able to build from Json?

Comment: you will need to add a service bean to exchange data with the view if you don't want the default constructor in the entity

Comment: I'm sorry but what is a service bean? how do i implement this?

Comment: I don't recall off the top of my head what it is, but I believe there's a Jackson annotation you can apply to the constructor to tell it to use that one to deserialize.

Comment: is that @JsonCreator ?

Comment: @chrylis yep it was that, i figured out and it works. But 'reos' solution's is great as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a  HttpMessageConverter, and receive the parameter as @RequestBody.

```
@RequestMapping(value= "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Classroom create(@RequestBodyClassroom classroom) {
    ... some checks ...
    return classroomManager.create(classroom);
}

public class ClassroomConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Classroom> {
...
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> httpMessageConverters) {
        httpMessageConverters.add(new ClassroomConverter(new MediaType("text", "csv")));
    }
}
```

Here there is a case similar to yours

http://www.beabetterdeveloper.com/2013/07/spring-mvc-requestbody-and-responsebody.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by defining Jackson custom deserializer for your model class.
Look at the link below on how to implement and configure it.

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization